# Triple integral over volume bounded by two cylinders

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm given the following triple integral $$\iiint_W y^2|z|\,dx\,dy\,dz$$ where $W=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3, \ 1\le x^2+y^2\le2x, \ 0\le z\le \displaystyle\frac{2}{x}  \right\}$.

The two cylinders have equations $x^2+y^2=1$ and $(x-1)^2+ y^2=1$. In the $xy-$plane, the two circles intersect at $x=1/2$. Since $x$ varies from $1/2$ to $2$, $2/x$ varies from $1$ to $4$, therefore $z$ is nonnegative and the modululs disappears. Evaluating the triple integral, I get
$$\iiint_W y^2|z|\,dx\,dy\,dz=\iint_D \left(\int_0^{\frac{2}{x}} y^2z\,dz \right)\,dx\,dy=2\iint_D \frac{y^2}{x^2}\,dx\,dy$$ where $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, x^2+y^2\ge1, (x-1)^2+y^2\le1 \}$.

Using the polar change of coordinates
\begin{cases}
x=\rho\cos\theta \\
y=\rho\sin\theta
\end{cases}
I find that $\rho\ge1$ and $\rho\le2\cos\theta$. Knowing that in the $xy-$plane $x\ge0$, I consider that $-\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{2}$. However, my textbook says that $\displaystyle-\frac{\pi}{3}\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{3}$, and I can't figure out why this restriction.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are interested only in the shaded area ($XY$ plane). For $|\theta| \gt \frac{\pi}{3}$, you are in region which is not of intersection.

As you said, $1 \leq \rho \leq 2 \cos \theta$. For $|\theta| \gt \frac{\pi}{3}$, $2 \cos \theta \lt 1$

[image]